# How can I use this font?

Tags: wpf, xaml, fonts, uwp

I want to use a custom `otf` font in my Universal Windows Application, but I can't get it to work.

I am currently using this in my `xaml`:

```
<TextBlock
    FontSize="16"
    Text="Question"
    FontFamily="../Assets/Fonts/NeoSansStdMedium.otf#Neo Sans Std Medium"/>
```

The font is located in `Assets/Fonts`, like so:

```
Project.Windows (Windows 8.1)
  > Assets
      > Fonts
          > NeoSansStdMedium.otf
```

And Windows Fontviewer shows the font name as:

```
Neo Sans Std Medium
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you embed the font (build actions)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd In Properties `Build Action` is `Content`. Setting `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource` doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font name after the # has to match the font name, and in this case apparently the `Medium` is not part of the name...

Some more info: I set the `.otf` file's properties to `Build Action: Content` and `Copy to Output Directory: Do not Copy`.

The XAML excerpt now looks like this:

```
<TextBlock
    FontSize="16"
    Text="Question"
    FontFamily="../Assets/Fonts/NeoSansStdMedium.otf#Neo Sans Std"/>
```